# add new Domain to Google Domain

Tags: web, hosting, cname

I am trying to create New Domain on Google Domain ...But I am getting stuck on these settings

[image]

Where Do I suppose to add TXTName or CNAME Record ? ....
I have seen some tutorial , but they are referring to Godaddy or Bluehost .. I dont wanna add on them . I wanna add on Google Domain ..

What is something I am missing ? is there any reference to add on google Domain

Answer (score 0):

Click verify, it will then fail, go to the register portion of Google domains and at the bottom add the required records to the appropriate domain.